# Program stops responding when deployed

Tags: c#, freeze

I am having a problem where my application works fine on the development enviroment, but when deployed to a customer just hangs without tripping any exceptions.

In order to deploy I have to change the login details (removed) and sql statements to those shown, which I suppose might be the issue but I'd expect any sql syntex errors to throw an exception. I have excluded infinite loops as a possibility (I think).

The only possibility I'm aware of is to use multithreading and hope the problem is solved, but I don't have that kind of time unless I can be certain that is the solution.

Frankly I'm at a loss and any tips / advice for extracting any kind of lead on the problem is appricated.

Here is the code:

```
        but_exit.Enabled = false;
        but_manual.Enabled = false;

        //switch off gui timer to allow process messages
        guiTimer.Enabled = false;
        lbl_dyn_status.Text = "Finding records...";

        /*create connection resources*/

        /*MYSQl*/
        //connect to mysql
        /*

         */

        var db_name = "";
        var db_host = "";
        var db_user = "";
        var db_password = "";

        var connectionString = "SERVER=" + db_host + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
    db_name + ";" + "UID=" + db_user + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + db_password + ";";
        MySqlConnection mysql_con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        //Create a list to store the  result
        List<string>[] mysql_idlist = new List<string>[1];
        mysql_idlist[0] = new List<string>();


        /*MSSQL*/
        //connect to mssyql



        db_user = "";
        db_password = "";
        db_name = "";
        db_host = "";

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection mssql_con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        mssql_con.ConnectionString = "SERVER=" + db_host + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
    db_name + ";" + "UID=" + db_user + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + db_password + ";";

        //Create a list to store the result
        List<string>[] mssql_idlist = new List<string>[2];
        mssql_idlist[0] = new List<string>();
        mssql_idlist[1] = new List<string>();

        /*Processing logic*/

        //first pass on mysql
        try
        {
            mysql_con.Open();

            //get id list
            string mysql_idlist_query = "SELECT product_code FROM cscart_products";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(mysql_idlist_query, mysql_con);

            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                mysql_idlist[0].Add(dataReader["product_code"] + "");
            }

            //close Data Reader
            dataReader.Close();

            //test content
            /*foreach (var id in mysql_idlist[0]) {
                lbl_dev.Text = lbl_dev.Text + id + " - ";
            }*/

            //close mysql connection
            mysql_con.Close();
        }

        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {

            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    lbl_dev.Text = "(mysql) Cannot connect to server. Contact administrator";
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    lbl_dev.Text = "(mysql) Invalid username/password, please try again";
                    break;

                default:
                    lbl_dev.Text = "Unknown mysql error.";
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            lbl_dev.Text = "first mysql error";
        }


        //first pass on mssql
        try
        {
            mssql_con.Open();

            //get id list
            //protect for duplicate skus
            string mssql_idlist_query = "SELECT substring (RIGHT('00'+ CAST (JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] AS varchar), 2) + CAST( ID AS Varchar ), patindex('%[^0]%',RIGHT('00'+ CAST (JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] AS varchar), 2) + CAST( ID AS Varchar )), 10) as SKU, ID FROM Denton_multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour WHERE substring (RIGHT('00'+ CAST (JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] AS varchar), 2) + CAST( ID AS Varchar ), patindex('%[^0]%',RIGHT('00'+ CAST (JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] AS varchar), 2) + CAST( ID AS Varchar )), 10) IN (SELECT substring(RIGHT('00'+ CAST (JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] AS varchar), 2) + CAST( ID AS Varchar ), patindex('%[^0]%',RIGHT('00'+ CAST (JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] AS varchar), 2) + CAST( ID AS Varchar )), 10))";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mssql_idlist_query, mssql_con);

            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                mssql_idlist[0].Add(dataReader["SKU"] + "");
                mssql_idlist[1].Add(dataReader["ID"] + "");
            }

            //close Data Reader
            dataReader.Close();
            mssql_con.Close();
        }

        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    lbl_dev.Text = "(mssql) Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator";
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    lbl_dev.Text = "(mssql) Invalid username/password, please try again";
                    break;

                default:
                    lbl_dev.Text = "Unknown mssql error. " + ex.Number; ;
                    break;
            }


        }
        catch
        {
            lbl_dev.Text = "first mssql error";
        }


        //compare lists and get ids that need inserting in mysql
        List<string>[] insert_idlist = new List<string>[10];
        insert_idlist[0] = new List<string>();//product code
        insert_idlist[1] = new List<string>();//short description
        insert_idlist[2] = new List<string>();//full description
        insert_idlist[3] = new List<string>();//product id
        insert_idlist[4] = new List<string>();//weight
        insert_idlist[5] = new List<string>();//rrp price
        insert_idlist[6] = new List<string>();//our price
        insert_idlist[7] = new List<string>();//categories
        insert_idlist[8] = new List<string>();//denton side id
        insert_idlist[9] = new List<string>();//insert / update tag
        List<string> dup_list = new List<string>();

        var about_to_insert = 0;

        foreach (var id in mssql_idlist[0])
        {
            if (mysql_idlist[0].Contains(id) == false)
            {
                //insert list
                insert_idlist[0].Add(id);
                insert_idlist[9].Add("i");
            }
            else
            {
                //update_list
                insert_idlist[0].Add(id);
                insert_idlist[9].Add("u");
            }
        }

        //construct full mssql dataset for insert items
        //final pass on mssql
        try
        {
            mssql_con.Open();


            foreach (var id in insert_idlist[0])
            {
                //top 1 for duplicate removal
                var mssql_select = "SELECT Denton_Multi.dbo.tblproductcategorys.*, Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.*, substring(RIGHT('00'+ CAST (Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] AS varchar), 2) + CAST( ID AS Varchar ), patindex('%[^0]%',RIGHT('00'+ CAST (Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] AS varchar), 2) + CAST( ID AS Varchar )), 10) as SKU, suppliers.[supplier name], (select top 1 [item description] from Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture4item where [supplier code] = Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[supplier code] and [item code] = Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[item code] And [Delete] = 0) as [item description], (select top 1 [model description] from Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture3Range where [supplier code] = Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[supplier code] and [model code] = Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[model code]) as [range description] FROM Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour join Denton_Multi.dbo.tblproductcategorys on Denton_Multi.dbo.tblproductcategorys.CategoryID = Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] join Denton_Multi.dbo.Suppliers on Denton_Multi.dbo.Suppliers.[supplier code] = Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[supplier code] WHERE ExportWeb = 1 AND substring(RIGHT('00'+ CAST (Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] AS varchar), 2) + CAST( ID AS Varchar ), patindex('%[^0]%',RIGHT('00'+ CAST (Denton_Multi.dbo.JH_TblFurniture6Colour.[product group] AS varchar), 2) + CAST( ID AS Varchar )), 10) = '"+id+"'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mssql_select, mssql_con);

                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Read the data and store them in the list
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    insert_idlist[1].Add(dataReader["Supplier Name"] + " " + dataReader["Range Description"] + " " + dataReader["Item Description"]);
                    insert_idlist[3].Add(dataReader["Sale Price"] + "");
                    insert_idlist[2].Add(dataReader["WebDesc"] + "");
                    //insert_idlist[3].Add(dataReader["id"] + "");removed
                    insert_idlist[4].Add(dataReader["WebDimensions"] + "");
                    insert_idlist[5].Add(dataReader["RRP"] + "");
                    insert_idlist[6].Add(dataReader["Normal Price"] + "");
                    insert_idlist[7].Add("482"); //add me
                    insert_idlist[8].Add(dataReader["ID"] + "");

                    about_to_insert = about_to_insert + 1;

                }
                lbl_dyn_status.Text = "Record 0 of " + about_to_insert + "updated.";

                dataReader.Close();

            }


            //close mysql connection
            mssql_con.Close();
        }

        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    lbl_dev.Text = "(mssql) Cannot connect to server. Contact administrator";
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    lbl_dev.Text = "(mssql) Invalid username/password, please try again";
                    break;

                default:
                    lbl_dev.Text = "Unknown mssql error. "+ex.Number;
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            lbl_dev.Text = "second mssql error";
        }



        //insert data in mysql db
        try
        {
            //final mysql pass
            var inc = insert_idlist[0].Count() - 1;

            if (about_to_insert > 0 && insert_idlist[0][0].Count() > 0)
            {


                mysql_con.Open();
                for (int x = 0; x <= inc; x++)
                {
                    int pid = 0;
                    if (insert_idlist[9][x] == "u")
                    {
                        //get web side product_id for updates
                        var sku = insert_idlist[0][x];
                        var get_id = "SELECT product_id FROM cscart_products WHERE product_code = '" + sku + "' LIMIT 1";
                        MySqlCommand do_get_id = new MySqlCommand(get_id, mysql_con);
                        MySqlDataReader rpid = do_get_id.ExecuteReader();

                        //get id
                        while (rpid.Read())
                        {
                            pid = Convert.ToInt32(rpid["product_id"]);
                        }
                        rpid.Close();
                    }


                    /*main record*/
                    var mysql_product = "";

                    if (insert_idlist[9][x] == "u")
                    {
                        mysql_product = "UPDATE cscart_products SET product_code = @product_code, list_price = @rrp, status='D' WHERE product_id = '" + pid + "'";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mysql_product = "INSERT INTO cscart_products (product_code, list_price, status) VALUES (@product_code, @rrp, 'D')";
                    }
                    MySqlCommand product_insert = new MySqlCommand(mysql_product, mysql_con);

                    product_insert.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@product_code", insert_idlist[0][x]));
                    product_insert.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@rrp", insert_idlist[5][x]));


                    product_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    var insertid = product_insert.LastInsertedId;

                    //get mssql id records
                    var sql_ID = insert_idlist[8][x];
                    var stock_sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TblSupplierDelivery INNER JOIN dbo.TblManagerStockListings ON dbo.TblSupplierDelivery.ID = dbo.TblManagerStockListings.ID WHERE dbo.TblSupplierDelivery.ID = '" + sql_ID + "'";

                    mssql_con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stock_sql, mssql_con);

                    //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                    SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    //insert extended data fields
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        var delivery_time = dataReader["Delivery Weeks"];
                        var stock_quant = Convert.ToInt16(dataReader["WHTotal"]) - Convert.ToInt16(dataReader["TotalAv"]);
                        var sale_price = insert_idlist[3][x];
                        var prod_ex = "";

                        if (insert_idlist[9][x] == "u")
                        {
                            prod_ex = "UPDATE cscart_oo_product_extend SET product_id = '" + pid + "', transfer_date = now(), sale_price = '" + sale_price + "', stock_due_date = '" + delivery_time + "' WHERE product_id = '" + pid + "'";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prod_ex = "INSERT INTO cscart_oo_product_extend (product_id, transfer_date, sale_price, stock_due_date) VALUES ('" + insertid + "', now(), '" + sale_price + "', '" + delivery_time + "')";
                        }
                        MySqlCommand product_ex_insert = new MySqlCommand(prod_ex, mysql_con);
                        product_ex_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //this is always an update
                        if (Convert.ToString(insertid) == "0")
                        {
                            insertid = pid;
                        }
                        var stock_insert = "UPDATE cscart_products SET amount = '" + stock_quant + "' WHERE product_id = '" + insertid + "'";
                        MySqlCommand product_stock_insert = new MySqlCommand(stock_insert, mysql_con);
                        product_stock_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    //close Data Reader
                    dataReader.Close();
                    mssql_con.Close();


                    /*description*/
                    var mysql_desc = "";
                    if (insert_idlist[9][x] == "u")
                    {
                        mysql_desc = "UPDATE cscart_product_descriptions SET product_id = @id, product = @product_name, full_description = @product_desc WHERE product_id = @id";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mysql_desc = "INSERT INTO cscart_product_descriptions (product_id, product, full_description) VALUES (@id, @product_name, @product_desc)";
                    }

                    MySqlCommand product_desc = new MySqlCommand(mysql_desc, mysql_con);

                    product_desc.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", insertid));
                    product_desc.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@product_name", insert_idlist[1][x]));
                    product_desc.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@product_desc", insert_idlist[2][x]));

                    product_desc.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //category
                    var mysql_cat = "";
                    if (insert_idlist[9][x] == "i")
                    {
                        mysql_cat = "INSERT INTO cscart_products_categories (product_id, category_id) VALUES (@id, @cat_id)";

                        MySqlCommand product_cat = new MySqlCommand(mysql_cat, mysql_con);

                        product_cat.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", insertid));
                        product_cat.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@cat_id", insert_idlist[7][x]));
                        product_cat.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    //price
                    var mysql_price = "";
                    if (insert_idlist[9][x] == "u")
                    {
                        mysql_price = "UPDATE cscart_product_prices SET product_id = @id, price = @our_price, lower_limit = '1' WHERE product_id = @id";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mysql_price = "INSERT INTO cscart_product_prices (product_id, price, lower_limit) VALUES (@id, @our_price, '1')";
                    }
                    MySqlCommand product_price = new MySqlCommand(mysql_price, mysql_con);

                    product_price.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", insertid));
                    product_price.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@our_price", insert_idlist[6][x]));

                    product_price.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    lbl_dyn_status.Text = "Record " + x + " of " + about_to_insert + "updated.";
                }


                mysql_con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            lbl_dev.Text = "upload error";
        }

        //reset gui timer for next idle period
        minutes_left = 10;
        lbl_dyn_status.Text = "Time until next automatic update: " + minutes_left + " minutes.";
        guiTimer.Start();

        but_exit.Enabled = true;
        but_manual.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: What framework is the project targetted at? What framework does the client have installed?

Comment: Figure out what added library/dll was installed on your dev box but isn't getting deployed to the client. If that doesn't work, add logging, even simple logging like File.AppendAllText calls at the beginning and end of your functions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx

Comment: This is written with .net and the client has the .net framework installed.

Comment: There are several versions of the .net framework.  What .net framework is your application targeted at?  How are you deploying the application?  Are you creating a setup project.  My advise would be to create a setup project for the application?  It should then download and install any prerequisits the client machine is missing.  It does sound like your application is using something that is not on your client machine.

Comment: @zeencat At the moment, just copying the release bin across. I will try using the setup route though.

Comment: @tracertong I would also check what .net framework your application is targetted at and then check what .net frameworks are on your client machine.  I would also becareful of installing any newer versions of the .net framework on a customers machine.  I've found that not all customers want to upgrade to the latest .net frameworks.  It only happens when their IT depts want to.  Its easier to change the .net framework of your application than upgrading a customers machine especially if its a server your deploying it to.

Comment: Hi Zeencat. The targeted .net framework is Framework 4 client, which is installed on the client machine.

Comment: It does look quite messy. you mightbe best checking this a section ata  time, got though the debugger line by line.. tedious, but you will find the problem. If he tried to run this on a client machine that didnt have the correct Framework he would get an error message indicating that, ive done it before :-P

Comment: @Derek. How can I do that sort of debugging in a production enviroment?

Comment: Another note is that you have a DB connection in the mix, that is always a point of concern for hangs.  A good spot for adding logging ...

Comment: Have yoy tried putting a timeout on your connection to the Database?

Comment: Another Point, Your Try catch Block Statements are all custom. You should change all of these to OleDbException, Exception etc etc. If your form is hanging when  loading, then how can you expect to see any errors that are been handled in a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have determined the issue is with slow response from an sql statement